# c++ simple remove vector duplicates causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am trying to practice basic algorithm and am keep receiving segmentation error while running on my mac vscode.

Can any one help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &nums)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itr = nums.begin();
    int prev = *itr;
    for(itr = ++itr ; itr != nums.end() ; itr++) {
        if(*itr == prev) {
            nums.erase(itr);
        } else {
            prev = *itr;
        }
    }
    itr = nums.begin();
    for(; itr != nums.end(); itr++) {
        cout<<*itr<<endl;
    }
    return 1;
}

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> test1;
    test1.push_back(1);
    test1.push_back(1);
    test1.push_back(1);
    test1.push_back(2);
    test1.push_back(2);
    test1.push_back(3);
    test1.push_back(3);
    test1.push_back(3);
    removeDuplicates(test1);
}
```

The problem in the terminal is
**[Done] exited with code=139 in 0.59 seconds**, where code=139 seems to imply the segmentation error.

Is this the problem with my local running environment or is it the problem with the logic?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) followed by [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)? Or considering that you add elements to the vector in an ordered fashion already, just `std::unique`.

Comment: It always makes me smile when beginners wonder if the problem might be something other than their faulty code.

Comment: @john thanks john haha you are correct :) fixed my code with comment of other great programmers!

Comment: @john and then when you *really* stumble across a fault caused by something or someone else you continue wondering for too long about what could be wrong with the code

Comment: @jamesdean Great, I think everyone has made the mistake you made at some time (several times in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the return value from `erase` function to be the new value of `itr`. You have to do this because the erase action invalidates the iterator.